# Error in install.packages : no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, dplyr, package

Since this morning, all my attempts to install packages result in the error message in the title. Installing packages worked fine before.

For example:

```
> install.packages("gapminder")
Error in install.packages : no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
```

It seems like, all of a sudden, the `install.packages` is making a call to the `filter` function from `dplyr`, which I had previously loaded through the `tidyverse` package.

I try unloading `tidyverse` before installing packages, but it now seems like `install.packages` considers tidyverse as a required package for **all** the other packages, e.g.:

```
> unloadNamespace("tidyverse")
> install.packages("gapminder")
Loading required package: tidyverse
Error in install.packages : no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
```

The same occurs with other methods for unloading packages and other packages, e.g.,

```
> detach("package:tidyverse", unload=TRUE)
> install.packages("stringdist")
Loading required package: tidyverse
Error in install.packages : no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Any idea what's causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: Need to quote package names: `install.packages("gapminder")` The rest of the confusion might be cleared up by getting rid of your `.Rdata` file. It appears corrupt. Start with a completely fresh R setup and use quotes.

Comment: @IRTFM Sorry, that was a wrong copy-paste, the package names were quoted in my queries, I'll make an edit. Thanks for the suggestion about the `.Rdata`. I don't understand how, but it did solve the problem.

Comment: If it is an .Rdata problem, change your global settings to:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YcNt.png

Comment: @Austin That's an Rstudio-based solution and this questioner didn't say he was on Rstudio (although I will admit that he probably was.) Sometimes you tidyverse users assume that everyone uses Rstudio. That's not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so the question is marked as answered: Following @IRTFM suggestion, I deleted the `.Rdata` file and it solved the problem (it wasn't clear from the question but I was using Rstudio).